# Git: checking out a file from a previous commit and amending it to HEAD

Tags: git, version-control

I recently committed a file to the HEAD of my branch which has errors in it. I need to do the following things:

- Get that file from one commit previous to HEAD
- Commit that file back into HEAD

What's the best way of going about that?

Comment: The easiest would be to copy the file content from that particular commit using a ui client (or from github bitbucket etc) and paste it in your current file and commit :) Easier than writing the hash and path

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You've practically said it yourself:

First get the file back from one commit before:

```
$> git checkout HEAD~1 path/to/file.ext
```

Then commit it:

```
$> git commit -a -m 'Retrieved file from older revision'
```

If only the changes to that file were present in the last commit, you can even use `git revert`:

```
$> git revert HEAD
```

I think it would be better to make this a separate commit, because it tells you exactly what you've reverted, and why. However, you can squash this into the previous commit by using the `--amend` switch to `git commit`.

Comment: --amend would be a switch for git commit, not git add

Comment: git-revert *would* make a separate commit (it was not entirely clear from your description). Using "git commit --amend" would correct last commit, instead of creating a new on (but you cannot do this if you published this part of history)

Comment: @bdonlan Even if you choose to use --amend you will still need to add the new file using either 'git add the_file.c' or using both options: git commit -a --amend

Comment: If you want to checkout the file from another commit, instead of `HEAD~1` use that commit's 10 digit id number shown on the right site of github's commit history.

Comment: This only works if the last commit hash (HEAD^ or HEAD~1) changed the file, the last commit hash can be updated other files instead this, see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull, in this scenario:

```
Commit hash - File modified
aaaaaaa       index.php
bbbbbbb       test.php
ccccccc       index.php
```

Git checkout HEAD~1 (or HEAD^) index.php try to checkout the index.php file to previous HEAD hash (bbbbbbb) but this is not the real previous commit hash file, is ccccccc. In the previous HEAD hash, index.php still remain unchanged because the last changed was made in hash ccccccc.

To revert some file to previous commit hash that affected the file, use:

```
git log -n 2 --pretty=format:%h path/to/file.ext
```

Ignore first hash and take the second hash, then:

```
git checkout <second_hash> path/to/file.ext
git commit -m 'Revert this file to real previous commit'
```