# using git locally

Tags: git, local-storage

I am new to git and if this ques is simple then please bear me.

1. I need to use git locally (I don't need to save my codes on server but in some another   directory locally).
2. 'git log' gives us details about all the commits made on project . If I want to see a file before a particular commit , how do i do that.

Comment: Please ask one question in a post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: checking out a file from a previous commit and amending it to HEAD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900560/git-checking-out-a-file-from-a-previous-commit-and-amending-it-to-head)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. doesn't seem to be a question. Git works fine locally.
2. `git checkout COMMIT^ -- path/to/file` for some commit hash `COMMIT` will check out the version of the file from directly before that commit.

Comment: 1. Just execute git init in the directory and you're good to go.